# how to identify the male-female and female-male jumper wires?

Tags: wire, jumper

I know it is a basic question but still I am confused , I wanted to use the female-male jumper wires on my basic electronic project ,So my question is how Can I identify which is female-male or male-female jumper wires?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but it's hard to guess what you are talking about. Maybe some pictures would help.

Comment: normally they are used to interconnect the components of a breadboard or other prototype or test circuit, internally or with other equipment or components, without soldering

Comment: You do get that 'male-female' can become 'female-male' by rotating 180 degrees?

Comment: Females have a hole, males have a bit that sticks out. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: jumper wire connectors]
left: male connectors; right: female connectors

Comment: @AJAY If you just wanted to know that, why do you ask for the differences between "female-male" and "male-female"? You realize there is no difference between both, then?

Comment: @dim I wanted to use female jumper wires for my project , and I didn't know the difference that's why I am asking such question.